# Dynamic user friendly url in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I know how to make user friendly url in cakephp using route. And I also know how to make url rewriting in .htaccess. But I have a requirement where I have to use username and its id in encrypted to its custom url. In the controller method I am passing only id as its argument. And based on that id it is showing me the profile page of that user.

I have url like this.

```
www.example.com/profile/<encrypted_id>
```

But I want like this

```
  www.example.com/<member name associate to that id>/<encrypted_id>
```

Everyday 100 of user are signing up so I have to make it dynamic. Is there any suggestion or way to do it.

Comment: So far I have done this in route. I have run a sql query there and retrieve all the records and make dynamic user friendly link over there. But I think it is not a good way because as my member table become heavy the query will take significant time.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want this format: www.example.com/profile/<member name associate to that id>/<encrypted_id> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a route

```
Router::connect('/:username/*', array('controller' => '...', 'action' => '...'), array('pass' => array('username'))));
```

read the value in the controller:

```
function foobar($id = null) {
    debug($this->request->username);
    debug($id);
}
```

Comment: You can also include a regex for your `:username` token; if you have imposed restrictions on your usernames.